# Plots and images on A4 with gridspec

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-gridspec

I would like to create a summary A4 page for the results of some computations I have done.

These include both images and plot in a layout like the one the code below produces. Unfortunately, matplotlib makes the images very small and the plots very wide.

How can I make everything align nicely in a 2x6 grid, as in images are displayed square and plots have shape 1x2 and save it in portrait orientation?

[image: Desired Layout]

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

mpl.use('pdf')

img = np.random.standard_normal((20,20))
data = np.linspace(0,1,10000)    

title_fontsize = 'x-small'
fig = plt.figure()
fig.figsize = (6*5, 2*5)

ax = np.zeros(8, dtype=object)
gs = fig.add_gridspec(8, 2, width_ratios=[1,1])
ax[0] = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 0])
ax[1] = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 1])
ax[2] = fig.add_subplot(gs[1:3, :])
ax[3] = fig.add_subplot(gs[3, :])
ax[4] = fig.add_subplot(gs[4, 0])
ax[5] = fig.add_subplot(gs[4, 1])
ax[6] = fig.add_subplot(gs[5, :])
ax[7] = fig.add_subplot(gs[6, :])

ax[0].imshow(img)
ax[0].set_title('Covariance Operator', fontsize = title_fontsize)

ax[1].imshow(img)
ax[1].set_title('Sample', fontsize = title_fontsize)

ax[2].imshow(img)
ax[2].set_title('Truth', fontsize = title_fontsize)

ax[3].plot(data)
ax[3].set_title('Measurement', fontsize = title_fontsize)

ax[4].imshow(img)
ax[4].set_title('MCMC Reconstruction', fontsize = title_fontsize)

ax[5].imshow(img)
ax[5].set_title('FBP Reconstruction', fontsize = title_fontsize)

ax[6].plot(data)
ax[6].set_title('Heightscale', fontsize = title_fontsize)

ax[7].plot(data)
ax[7].set_title('Jump Size', fontsize = title_fontsize)

for x in ax.flat:
    for tick in x.xaxis.get_major_ticks():
        tick.label.set_fontsize('xx-small')
    for tick in x.yaxis.get_major_ticks():
        tick.label.set_fontsize('xx-small')

plt.savefig('test.pdf')
```

For reference, this is how the output looks like now:

[image: Current output (with real data)]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I changed the layout a little, but the solution was to set the figsize to that of A4 paper and adjusting the height ratios of `gs`. Also `fig.set_size_inches` takes width as first argument, then height.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

mpl.use('pdf')

img = np.random.standard_normal((20,20))
data = np.random.standard_normal((10000,2))
theta = [1,2]
description = 'Size: %s, #Samples: %s, Computation Time: %ss'%(25, 13, int(12.5))

title_fontsize = 'x-small'
fig = plt.figure(dpi=300, tight_layout=True)
fig.set_size_inches(8.27, 11.69, forward=True)

plt.figtext(0.02, .99, description, fontsize = 'small')

ax = np.zeros(9, dtype=object)
gs = fig.add_gridspec(5, 3, height_ratios=[3,2,3,2,2])
ax[0] = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 0])
ax[1] = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 1])
ax[2] = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 2])
ax[3] = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, :])
ax[4] = fig.add_subplot(gs[2, 0])
ax[5] = fig.add_subplot(gs[2, 1])
ax[6] = fig.add_subplot(gs[2, 2])
ax[7] = fig.add_subplot(gs[3, :])
ax[8] = fig.add_subplot(gs[4, :])

ax[0].imshow(img)
ax[0].set_title('Slice through Covariance Operator', fontsize = title_fontsize)

ax[1].imshow(img)
ax[1].set_title('Last Sample', fontsize = title_fontsize)

ax[2].imshow(img)
ax[2].set_title('Truth', fontsize = title_fontsize)

for i, d in enumerate(data.T):
    ax[3].plot(d, label = '%s°'%int(theta[i]))

ax[3].legend(loc='upper right')
ax[3].set_title('Measurement (Sinogram)', fontsize = title_fontsize)

ax[4].imshow(img)
ax[4].set_title('MCMC Reconstruction (Sample Mean)', fontsize = title_fontsize)

ax[5].imshow(img)
ax[5].set_title('MCMC Sample Variance', fontsize = title_fontsize)

ax[6].imshow(img)
ax[6].set_title('FBP Reconstruction', fontsize = title_fontsize)

ax[7].plot(data)
ax[7].set_title('Heightscale', fontsize = title_fontsize)

ax[8].plot([b[0] for b in data], label='Layer 1')
ax[8].plot([b[1] for b in data], label='Layer 0')
ax[8].legend(loc='upper right')
ax[8].set_title('Jump Size', fontsize = title_fontsize)
for x in ax.flat:
    for tick in x.xaxis.get_major_ticks():
        tick.label.set_fontsize('xx-small')
    for tick in x.yaxis.get_major_ticks():
        tick.label.set_fontsize('xx-small')

plt.savefig('test.pdf')
```

And a picture for reference:

[image: Correct Layout]